# What is the difference between platform events published and delivered?

Tags: platform-event

The reason I ask is because the allocations page states the "delivered" is half what the "published" limit is, which doesn't make sense as we can publish more messages than even a single subscriber can consume.

Comment: This question was asked almost 3 years ago but it still makes no sense to me. As @Deployment Failure asked, Salesforce states that in performance editions you can publish 250 000 events by hour but you can only deliver 50 000 events by day. So you can publish hundreds of thousands of events by days that are not delivered. Very useful !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Event Bus allows for multiple subscribers to an event, such as:

```
   Publisher 1           Publisher 2
        |     (publishes)     |
     Event 1               Event 2
    /   |   \             /   |   \
    |   |   | (delivered) |   |   |
 Client | Client       Client | Client
   1  Client  3          4  Client  6
        2                     5
```

In this example, if Publisher 1 "publishes" an event, Clients 1-3 will each get a "delivery," while if Publisher 2 "publishes" a different event, Clients 4-6 will each get a "delivery."

The limits, therefore, allow for an average of 2 clients per event published.

Comment: Thanks for the vizulisation, I got my wording wrong in the question. The allocations page states the published number is double what the delivered count is, so even with ONE consumer the total number events cant be subscribed to.